# cakePHP duplicating a function or using an outer controller? (DRY issue)

Tags: php, cakephp, dry, cakephp-model, code-duplication

I have 3 controllers, `Tokens, Stores` and `Users`.

Token is related to the two other models, for each token there is a owner-type and owner-id.

There is also a function in both User_controller and Store_controller, called EmailTokenToUser which send the activation link to the person that registered a user or a store.

My question is: should i pass the function to the token?
if so, how should i call it? (requestAction is a bad idea, creating an object just for one function..)

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reuse code you should pass it to token's MODEL not the controller. That is the way it should be not the only way. To use it you should NOT use requestAction even if is inside the controller (again it is the way it should be you CAN do it with requestAction). You can do this in two ways.

```
App:import('model', Token');
Token::myFunction($args);
```

OR

```
$token = ClassRegistry:init('Token');
$token->myFunction($args);
```

OR (if you are colling it from inside a controller you may use also)

```
$this->loadModel('Token');
$this->Token->myFunction($args);
```

This is if you put it in the Token model the function. If not and go with the controller way you should do it like this

```
App:import('controller', 'Tokens');
TokensController::myFunction($args);
```

OR

```
App:import('controller', 'Tokens');
$token = new TokensController();
$token->myFunction($args);
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Great. tho, one question: should i load the model if it is related? can't i just `$this->LocalModel->RelatedModel->function()` ?

Comment: yes you can do that since it is already loaded. It should work